# Dynamics CRM online V 9 Deploy packages using powershell - issues

Tags: powershell, dynamics-crm, powershell-3.0, powershell-cmdlet, dynamics-crm-365-v9

I am following [deploy-packages-using-package-deployer-windows-powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/dynamics365/customer-engagement/admin/deploy-packages-using-package-deployer-windows-powershell) Thread for the new V9 CRM SDK.

When running the RegisterXRMPackageDeployment.ps1 in powershell 3.0 as administrator, I get "**Cannot verify the Microsoft .NET Framework version 4.5.2 because it is not included in the list of permitted versions**" message and it continue exporting cmdlets.

But when I run Get-Help “Crm” command after I get error with "Get-Help :

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,......".

I am having a Windows 7 64 bit machine.

Answer (score 0):

If somebody is interested, I found the answer for my question.

We have to use the TLS12 security protocol to use PowerShell in .NET 4.5.2.

```
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
```

Found this on [this](http://chamindac.blogspot.com/2017/10/tls-12-powershell-and-dynamics-crm-with.html#more) blog